# How can I download an array of files from a website? wget?

Tags: arrays, list, file, download, wget

Let's say I want to download example.com/pics/0000.jpg through example.com/pics/9999.jpg.
What's the best way to do that?

I tried:

```
wget example.com/pics/{0000..9999].jpg
```

but it said "Argument list too long".

What's a good script or program I can use to do this?

I don't code much. I am thinking it will involve a shell script that uses wget to get 0000.jpg and then it will +1 to get the next picture, until it reaches 9999.jpg.

Thanks.

Comment: i hope that's a typo

Comment: I think your problem is that you close a curly bracket with a square bracket.

Comment: It was a typo. I didn't use that address when I tried because it obviously wouldn't work and gave me the correct error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Bash one-liner that does what you want:

```
for n in $(seq -f "%04g" 0 9999); do wget http://example.com/pics/$n.jpg; done
```

Comment: That worked great. Unfortunately it's very slow to move between files and someone else suggested to me to use a FIreFox extension "Down Them All". But still, thanks. I may use it in the future.